How do I force post-init field coersion?
Suppose I want a field to be coerced to a specific type:
@dataclass
class Foo:
    bar: Bar
    def __post_init__(self):
        self.bar = to_bar(self.bar)

is __post_init__ the right way?

Yes, that looks good as long as to_bar can also accept a Bar object as an argument.  You could also to implement a Bar.load class method and use that instead of to_bar.

Hi, is it pydantic dataclass?

if you are not limited to standard library useage and open for 3rd party one, then pydantic is good one, where you can use validation function on bar which work same as post__init
